# How to get the hc-transform for a custom map?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps, proj4js

I have a GeoJson from brazil which is a more detailed version of the official HighMaps Brazil map. In this JSON I have the states divided into its mesoregions.

When I tried to draw a point on top of this GeoJson I got the message telling me that this functionality was only supported with official highmaps maps. Reading the [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon) I found out that I should create an object `hc-transform` on my geojson. I thought it would make sense to use the same `hc-transform` used by the official HighMaps Brazil map, and when I did, it kinda works ok: It gives me the the same point with `fromLatLonToPoint()` method but then when I use the method `toPixels()` to get the "canvas" position (and draw something on top of it) it gives me different values.

The code Im using is this (it works fine for brazil official highmaps):

```
let point = chart.fromLatLonToPoint({lat: n.lat, lon: n.long});
let x = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(point.x, true);
let y = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(point.y, true);
// Draw the div / point / whatever on the (x, y) position
```

The GeoJson I am talking about you can find here: https://github.com/Menighin/HighmapsExperiment/blob/master/geo/mesorregiao.json

Checking Highmaps oficial Brazilian map I can see that each polygon also has some highcharts attributes (`hc-middle-x`, `hc-middle-y`, etc). Does that make any difference? If not, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Turns out my `hc-transform` doesn't seem to be right as we can see on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0vm8a4x3/

If we uncoment the line 8, we can see that the city Belo Horizonte, is not plotted on the right position on the Mesoregion map.

So, how can I get the `hc-transform` right?

Comment: I see that you've crated a ticket on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7960 Let the discussion continue there. Another approach is that you can try to find the values of `scale`, `xoffset` and 'yoffset' by trial and error method (I'm not sure if it's gonna work): http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/onsau9u5/

Comment: Yes Kamil! Thanks! I actually solved it already (as I explained on Github as well). Turned out I was simply using the `crs` wrong. For some reason QGis was giving me the wrong proj4 string... Using the right one, everything works :)